# awk search and replace string in a specific column of CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file with 17 columns and million rows. I want to search for a specific string in the 16th column and replace all the instances of that string with another string.  Since my rest of the program uses bash script, I thought using awk instead of Python search & replace.  My current OS is Rhel6.

The following is the sample output of my data:

```
SUBSCRIBER_ID|ACCOUNT_CATEGORY|ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DATE|PACKAGE_NAME|PACKAGE_TYPE|DURATION|ACTIVE_DATE|INACTIVE_DATE|STB_NO|PRIMARY_SECONDARY|MODEL_TYPE|VC_NO|MULTIROOM|STB_TYPE|IPKG|SERVICE_STATE|CURRENT_STATUS
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual package 199 May17 pack|Basic Package|Annual|08/28/2017||027445053518|Primary|Pace - 31|000223871682|Yes|AMP|Package 199 pack|Market1|Active
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual Pack|Premium Package|Annual|08/28/2017||027445053518|Primary|Pace - 31|000223871682|Yes|AMP|English Movies pack|Market1|Active
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual SingleUnit Jun17 Pack|Secondary Pack|Annual|08/28/2017||032089364015|Secondary|Kaon|000017213968|Yes|AMP|SingleUnit|Market2|Active
```

In this the 16th column is Market, wherein I want to change the `Market1` to `MarketPrime`.  The name of the file is `marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv`

I tried the following code:

```
awk -F '| +' '{gsub("Market1","MarketPrime",$16); print}' OFS="|" marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv > marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv
```

This runs without any output, but the string `Market1` still remains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '$16 == "Market1" { $16 = "MarketPrime" }1' file.csv >new-file.csv
```

The only real issue in your code is that you set the input file separator to not just `|` but to spaces as well.  This will make the spaces count as field separators in the data and it will be incredibly hard to figure out what the correct field number is (since some fields contain a variable number of spaces).

You also can not redirect into the same filename as you use to read from.  Doing so would cause the shell to first truncate (empty) the output file, and your `awk` program would have no data to read.

Your code does a regular expression replacement.  This is ok, but you need to be aware that if the 16th field happens to be something like `Market12` or `TheMarket1`, it would trigger the substitution due to the missing anchor points. It would be safer to use `^Market1$` as the expression to replace, or to use a string comparison.

The `awk` command above uses only `|` as a field separator and then does a string comparison with the 16th field.  If that field is `Market1`, it is set to `MarketPrime`.

The trailing `1` at the end of the `awk` code causes every record (modified or not) to be printed.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked...but it removed the '|' pipe separator from the entire line wherever I had Market1, and hence those lines in the new file got jumbled up together.

Comment: @Apricot You did not run my command.  My command has `-v OFS='|'` on the command line. (or should have had, oops, sorry! Fixed now)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, when I changed the `awk -F '| +'` to `awk -F '|'` it worked perfectly....accepting your answer.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with input field separator.

Since you want to use multiple field separator(which is not required), the number of fields in each row is different as shown below.

```
$ awk -F '[| +]' '{print NF}' test.csv
17
26
23
21
```

if you use only `|`  as IFS, then your code will work. Since each row has 17 fields as shown below.

```
awk -F "|" '{print NF}' test.csv
17
17
17
17
```

**Solution 1**: with multiple IFS.

```
awk -F '[| +]' '{gsub("Market1","MarketPrime",$(NF-1)); print}' OFS="|" test.csv

SUBSCRIBER_ID|ACCOUNT_CATEGORY|ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DATE|PACKAGE_NAME|PACKAGE_TYPE|DURATION|ACTIVE_DATE|INACTIVE_DATE|STB_NO|PRIMARY_SECONDARY|MODEL_TYPE|VC_NO|MULTIROOM|STB_TYPE|IPKG|SERVICE_STATE|CURRENT_STATUS
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual|package|199|May17|pack|Basic|Package|Annual|08/28/2017||027445053518|Primary|Pace|-|31|000223871682|Yes|AMP|Package|199|pack|MarketPrime|Active
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual|Pack|Premium|Package|Annual|08/28/2017||027445053518|Primary|Pace|-|31|000223871682|Yes|AMP|English|Movies|pack|MarketPrime|Active
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual SingleUnit Jun17 Pack|Secondary Pack|Annual|08/28/2017||032089364015|Secondary|Kaon|000017213968|Yes|AMP|SingleUnit|Market2|Active
```

**Solution 2**: with fixed field 16

```
awk -F '|' '{gsub("Market1","MarketPrime",$16); print}' OFS="|" test.csv

SUBSCRIBER_ID|ACCOUNT_CATEGORY|ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DATE|PACKAGE_NAME|PACKAGE_TYPE|DURATION|ACTIVE_DATE|INACTIVE_DATE|STB_NO|PRIMARY_SECONDARY|MODEL_TYPE|VC_NO|MULTIROOM|STB_TYPE|IPKG|SERVICE_STATE|CURRENT_STATUS
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual package 199 May17 pack|Basic Package|Annual|08/28/2017||027445053518|Primary|Pace - 31|000223871682|Yes|AMP|Package 199 pack|MarketPrime|Active
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual Pack|Premium Package|Annual|08/28/2017||027445053518|Primary|Pace - 31|000223871682|Yes|AMP|English Movies pack|MarketPrime|Active
1001098068|ResidentialRegular|01/20/2007|Annual SingleUnit Jun17 Pack|Secondary Pack|Annual|08/28/2017||032089364015|Secondary|Kaon|000017213968|Yes|AMP|SingleUnit|Market2|Active
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity for others who may face similar issues:

Both these answers worked for this scenario:

Kusalananda's answer:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '$16 == "Market1" { $16 = "MarketPrime" }1' file.csv >new-file.csv
```

My revised answer based on Kusalananda's answer:

```
awk -F '|' '{gsub("Market1","MarketPrime",$16); print}' OFS="|" marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv > marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv
```

Comment: Take care that your input and output filenames are the same.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, `awk ... file >file` will truncate `file`, so that second command is not correct in that sense.  Also, the regular expression may potentially also replace strings other than exactly `Market1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{if($16=="Market1") $16="MarketPrime" ; print }' marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv > marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv
```

using this , you can change any word in the lane that matches with Market1, for exapmle, if you wanted to change the 17th word , just change it to

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{if($16=="Market1") $17="Thisiscool" ; print }' marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv > marketinfo_2018-06-26.csv
```

Comment: You overwriting the input with the output.